# Canvas window.inner(Width|Height) scrollbar offset?

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar

I made a game that sets the width and height of the canvas as window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight, respectively. In theory, this should make it flush with the sides, yet I get scrollbars and a 4 pixel height blank to the bottom of the page. I set the margins and paddings to * as 0, thinking that would solve it, yet it's still like that.

I need to use the least amount of code as possible; this is for a future js1k compo.

Here's a screenie of the page [Top-Left Scrolled Image](http://cl.ly/0k0Q0j3q2W3A1u231m3f), [Bottom-Right Scrolled Image](http://cl.ly/2h3F0H0I0E1n0X0w0602).

Any ideas on what is wrong or on how to fix it?

Comment: I had the doctype as `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but I added the 5 to the end of html, and now it's all fine :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing a `display: block` for your canvas element, or a `<!DOCTYPE html>` - they're inline by default unless you're in html5 mode.

Comment: I was testing my game in chrome, so this shouldn't be the problem. I did find a fix though. Post my comment (above) as the answer, and I'll make it the accepted answer