# What could be causing my canvas to overflow the screen when I run my code on Edge or Brave?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

The problem is the canvas is overflowing the screen if I don't set the display to block and I couldn't find an answer for this on the internet so it seemed to me that I might be doing something wrong. I'm testing this on Edge and Brave and I get the same results.

Can I know what is wrong with my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
/*
canvas {
  display: block;
}
*/
```

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

and this is the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/Louai99k/pen/xxyQEgg)

I tried to run the provided code and expected the canvas to fit the screen without having any scrollbars or overflowing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509176/canvas-window-innerwidthheight-scrollbar-offset

Comment: oh thanks. I saw a video on youtube he didn't set `display: block` but I think I missed something there. well what does the answer in your question means by 'activating html5 mode'?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the canvas element indeed needs `display: block` (since it's not block level in default) or we need to activate the html5 mode by transforming `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html5>`